# Where is .bash_profile?

Tags: macos, .bash-profile

I'm trying to follow the instructions here: http://www.ladysign-apps.com/developer/mac-osx-run-sublime-from-your-terminal/#.Vj0ZfYRqmj4.

Where is .bash_profile located?

I see a .bash_profile.swp in the root of my user folder.  Is that the same?

When I open it, it looks like this:

```
b0VIM 7.3������„(TÈï    �ÇÎmyuser�����������������������������MacBook-Pro.local�����������������������~myuser/.bash_profile���������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������utf-8
U3210����#"! U�������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������tp��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������ad��⁄��������������˚��˙��√��à��á��S������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������source '/Users/myuser/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc'�# The next line enables bash completion for gcloud.��source '/Users/myuser/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'�# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.��quit�
```

Where exactly am I supposed to add the following in .bash_profile?

> export PATH=~/bin:$PATH

-- UPDATE --

When I do `nano ~/.bash_profile` I see

```
# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
source '/Users/myuser/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'

# The next line enables bash completion for gcloud.
source '/Users/myuser/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc'
```

Where in there should I add

```
export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

Comment: @DavidPostill: I don't think so.

Comment: Really? You clearly didn't read it properly. "user-specific values may be given to those variables in scripts located in the home folder (e.g., /etc/profile, $HOME/.bash_profile)" in the section labelled OSX. if `$HOME/.bash_profile` doesn't exist then create it.

Comment: Real my question?  Is that .bash_profile.swp?  How do you edit it?  I'd vote you down but I can't.

Comment: No it's not. `bash_profile.swp` is some other file. You edit `~/.bash_profile` with your favourite editor.

Comment: Why do you want to vote someone down who is trying to help you?

Comment: It's the SO way.  Plus, your responses aren't helping.

Comment: Really? I've told you exactly what to do and where to find the information you need to know. You can add  `export PATH=~/bin:$PATH` at the end of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Where exactly am I supposed to add the following in .bash_profile?

```
export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
```

1. Open `~/.bash_profile` in your favourite editor.
2. Add `export PATH=~/bin:$PATH` at the end of the file.
3. Save the file.
4. Start a new shell or terminal and `PATH` will have been updated to include the `~/bin` directory.

---

#### Further Reading

- [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)